# Laravel ORM :one to many relation for getting total number of rows child table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've two tables `jobs` table (id,title,description)->Jobs model

and  `candinates` table (id,applied_job_id(FK jobs),user_id)->Candidate model

I want to get all the rows of jobs with the total number of candidate applied for each job

**Jobs model**

```
class Jobs extends Model
{

    public function appliedCount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Candidate','applied_job_id');
    }
}
```

**Candidate Model**

```
class Candidate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'candidate';
}
```

Here is my query

```
 $query = Jobs::limit($this->limit)->offset($offset)->get();
```

Currently it returns all the rows of `jobs` table

Note:
I will fetch the result as JSON

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the relationship with a non existent model `Candidate`, where as the model is named `JobActivity` which uses the table `candidate`, when the table is actually named `candidates`. Try this.

```
class Jobs extends Model
{
    public function candidate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class,'applied_job_id');
    }
}

class Candidate extends Model
{
}


$jobs = Jobs::withCount('candidate')->limit($this->limit)->offset($offset)->get();
```